# Html Nested Order List in TinyMce

Tags: html, tinymce

I want to create html nested ordered list in tinyMce.  Example of how I want it to display is as structure below.I'm facing problem in getting this result in TinyMce. In TinyMce , the listing could not display as 1.1,1.2. It display as 1,2.

```
1.Topic
  1.1 Subtopic 1
  1.2 Subtopic 2
```

I can achieve this result without using tinymce. But, it fails when run in tinymce.

Without TinyMce

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   ol 
   { 
    counter-reset: item 
   }
   li
   { 
    display: block 
   }
   li:before 
   { 
    content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item 
   }
   
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     
  <ol>
    <li>li element
      <ol>
        <li>sub li element</li>
        <li>sub li element</li>
        <li>sub li element</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>li element</li>
    <li>li element
      <ol>
        <li>sub li element</li>
        <li>sub li element</li>
        <li>sub li element</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
 </ol>  
 </body>
</html>
```

With TinyMce

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.0.16/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#full-featured-non-premium',
        plugins: 'print preview fullpage paste importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable help charmap quickbars emoticons',
        imagetools_cors_hosts: ['picsum.photos'],
        menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media template link anchor codesample | ltr rtl',
        toolbar_sticky: true,
        autosave_ask_before_unload: true,
        autosave_interval: "30s",
        autosave_prefix: "{path}{query}-{id}-",
        autosave_restore_when_empty: false,
        autosave_retention: "2m",
        image_advtab: true,
        content_css: [
          //'//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
          //'//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css'
          //'../../library/tinymce/css/font.css',
          //'../../library/tinymce/css/style.css'
          'css/style.css'
        ],
        link_list: [{
            title: 'My page 1',
            value: 'http://www.tinymce.com'
          },
          {
            title: 'My page 2',
            value: 'http://www.moxiecode.com'
          }
        ],
        image_list: [{
            title: 'My page 1',
            value: 'http://www.tinymce.com'
          },
          {
            title: 'My page 2',
            value: 'http://www.moxiecode.com'
          }
        ],
        image_class_list: [{
            title: 'None',
            value: ''
          },
          {
            title: 'Some class',
            value: 'class-name'
          }
        ],
        importcss_append: true,
        height: 400,
        file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
          /* Provide file and text for the link dialog */
          if (meta.filetype === 'file') {
            callback('https://www.google.com/logos/google.jpg', {
              text: 'My text'
            });
          }

          /* Provide image and alt text for the image dialog */
          if (meta.filetype === 'image') {
            callback('https://www.google.com/logos/google.jpg', {
              alt: 'My alt text'
            });
          }

          /* Provide alternative source and posted for the media dialog */
          if (meta.filetype === 'media') {
            callback('movie.mp4', {
              source2: 'alt.ogg',
              poster: 'https://www.google.com/logos/google.jpg'
            });
          }
        },
        templates: [{
            title: 'New Table',
            description: 'creates a new table',
            content: '<div class="mceTmpl"><table width="98%%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><th scope="col"> </th><th scope="col"> </th></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr></table></div>'
          },
          {
            title: 'Starting my story',
            description: 'A cure for writers block',
            content: 'Once upon a time...'
          },
          {
            title: 'New list with dates',
            description: 'New List with dates',
            content: '<div class="mceTmpl"><span class="cdate">cdate</span><br /><span class="mdate">mdate</span><h2>My List</h2><ul><li></li><li></li></ul></div>'
          }
        ],
        template_cdate_format: '[Date Created (CDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S]',
        template_mdate_format: '[Date Modified (MDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S]',
        height: 600,
        image_caption: true,
        quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote quickimage quicktable',
        noneditable_noneditable_class: "mceNonEditable",
        toolbar_drawer: 'sliding',
        contextmenu: "link image imagetools table",
      });


    });
  </script>
  <style>
    ol {
      counter-reset: item
    }

    li {
      display: block
    }

    li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".") " ";
      counter-increment: item
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="full-featured-non-premium" name="full-featured-non-premium">      
        <ol>
          <li>li element
            <ol>
              <li>sub li element</li>
              <li>sub li element</li>
              <li>sub li element</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>li element</li>
          <li>li element
            <ol>
              <li>sub li element</li>
              <li>sub li element</li>
              <li>sub li element</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
    </ol>

        </textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Result with TinyMce]

I want to know how to do list like 1.1,1.2 in TinyMce. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly noted, to get markers like the ones you want you need to use CSS.  There are no native marker types in HTML that look like what you want.

You can pass CSS into TinyMCE via the `content_css` setting and then apply classes to your list to get it styled as you like.  You can define the styles people can apply via the `style_formats` option.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#style_formats

Comment: `ol{
      counter-reset: item
    }

    ol > li{
      display: block
    }

    ol > li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".") " ";
      counter-increment: item
    }` .After placed this codes in content_css path file, it works.Thank you.